# illustrator blob brush is painting below the artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've never seen this in my 5years of AI experience where the blob brush has started painting below the artwork already on the layer.

Answer (score 1):

Hej, and welcome to GDSE. There are different drawing modes in Illustrator. Draw behind is one of them.
You can change this in the toolbar just beneath your color indicator:

[image: select drawing mode]